# Do I need to look for a key down and up event to avoid double occurrence of my else block?

Tags: python-3.x, keyboard-events

Wondering why its printing my else statement twice in this scenario. In theory it should just execute it once after an incorrect key is read, and loop back.
[the out put I am getting after pressing a non 'enter' key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkKnt.png) How can I avoid this?

```
import random
import keyboard

#Constant values to assign as a win or loss
_WIN = 1
_LOSE = 0

#Create and store game hand choices
handChoice = ['Spock', 'Lizard', 'Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']

print('\nThis is advanced Rock, Paper, Scissors! Press ENTER to start the automated game->')
while True:
    if keyboard.read_key() == 'enter':
        break
    else:
        print('Please press ENTER!')

#Hand choices randomly assigned to player 1
player1 = random.choice(handChoice)
print('Player 1 uses ' + player1 + '!\n')
```

Comment: You should read the docs, but there a probably 2 events: key down and key up. when you press a wrong key there are 2 wrong events and thus 2 print statements.

Comment: Oh ok, so thats why I was getting the error. Not aware how to fully utilize the docs for these kinds of problems yet sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking true [the docs](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard) you could use this:

```
keyboard.wait('enter')
```

It will also use less cpu. But you would need the async library with timeout to also give output.
you could also use this:

```
while True:
    if keyboard.read_key() == 'enter':
        break
    elif event.event_type == keyboard.KEY_DOWN:
        print('Please press ENTER!')
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for link to the docs, I should have checked those out prior to asking. I plan to utilize the async wait library later anyways, so I will look into that approach. Otherwise the second method you mentioned will work just fine. Thanks alot

Comment: If this answers your question could you accept it.

Comment: just did that apologies, barely post on here.